# Application icon not appearing next to application name in top bar while using Arc GNOME shell theme

Tags: themes, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I'm currently running Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on my laptop. I didn't like the default theme (Adwaita), so I replaced it with the Arc Icon, GTK+ and Shell theme.

The theme works fine, but I noticed that the icons that usually come next to the name of the currently running application in the top bar don't appear any more (e.g. While running Firefox, only the name appears. The Firefox logo doesn't).

Is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Yes... choose another theme, or go back to Adwaita :-)

Comment: @heynnema I actually found a solution to this myself. I opened the `gnome-shell.css` file in `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/`, and edited the .app-menu-icon class. I changed the width and height from 0 to 100%. It now works perfectly (I also adjusted the padding a bit).

Comment: See how smart you are! Good fix! Thanks for the update! Why don't you post an answer with a snippet of the code that you changed, and explain what/why you did it? Include some pictures if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the `gnome-shell.css` file in `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/`, and edit the `.app-menu-icon` class. Change the width and height from `0` to `100%`. Also adjust the padding if needed.

It should now work perfectly.

---

<sub>Source: [Comment by OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/939275/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-application-icon-not-appearing-next-to-application-name-in#comment1498285_939275) (should have been posted as an answer)</sub>